# Shear stress and surface heat transfer rate with various Pr values

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, flow, convection

I'm revising for my Fluid Mechanics exam, and came across a question that ask us to explain the behaviour of the shear stress and surface heat transfer rate with various Pr values.

> The question is describing a steady boundary layer flow and heat transfer past a sphere of radius $a$ in a forced convection flow of a viscous and incompressible fluid of free stream velocity $U_\infty$ and ambient temperature $T_\infty$. It is assumed that the sphere is kept at the uniform temperature $T_w$ and the boundary layer approximation are valid. The dimensional governing equations are:
>   $$\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{x}}(\bar{r} \bar{u})+\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{y}}(\bar{r} \bar{v}) = 0\\
> \rho \left( \bar{u} \frac{\partial \bar{u}}{\partial \bar{x}}+\bar{v} \frac{\partial \bar{u}}{\partial \bar{y}} \right)=\rho \bar{u_e} \frac{d\bar{u_e}}{d\bar{x}}+\mu \frac{\partial^2 \bar{u}}{\partial \bar{y}^2} \\
> \bar{u} \frac{\partial T}{\partial \bar{x}}+\bar{v} \frac{\partial T}{\partial \bar{y}}=\alpha \frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial \bar{y}^2}$$ 
>   subject to the boundary conditions
>   $$\bar{u}=\bar{v}=0, \qquad T = T_w \qquad \mathrm{at} \quad \bar{y}=0, \\
> \bar{u} \rightarrow \bar{u_e}(\bar{x}), \qquad T\rightarrow T_\infty, \qquad \mathrm{as} \quad \bar{y} \rightarrow \infty$$
>   where $\bar{x}$ and $\bar{y}$ are the Cartesian coordinates measured along the sphere and normal to it, $\bar{u}$ and $\bar{u}$ are velocity components along $\bar{x}$ and $\bar{y}$ respectively. $\mu$ is the dynamic viscosity and $\alpha$ is the thermal diffusivity of the fluid. $\bar{r}$ i the distance from the symmetrical axis to the surface oof the sphere and $\bar{u}_e(\bar{x})$ is the local free stream velocity which is given as $(3/2)U_\infty \sin(\bar{x}/a)$
>
> By using non similarity variables of the following form:
>   $$\psi = xrf(x,y) , \qquad \theta = g(x,y)=\frac{T-T_\infty}{T_{wall}-T_\infty}$$ 
>   We can reduce the governing equations(momentum and equation) to the non-dimensional form:
>   $$\frac{\partial^3 f}{\partial y^3}+\left( 1+\frac{x}{\sin x}\cos x \right)f\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2} - \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \right)^2 + \frac{9}{4} \frac{\sin x \cos x}{x}  \\ =x \left( 
> \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} - \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2} \right)$$
>
> $$\frac{1}{Pr} \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial y^2}+\left( 1+\frac{x}{\sin x}\cos x \right)f\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}=x\left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} -\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\partial g}{\partial y} \right)$$ 
>   with the boundary conditions :
>   $$f=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=0, \qquad g=1, \qquad \mathrm{at} \quad y=0 \\
> \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\rightarrow \frac{3}{2} \frac{\sin x}{x}, \qquad g \rightarrow 0 \qquad \mathrm{as} \quad y\rightarrow \infty$$
>   $x$ and $y$ are the non-dimensional Cartesian coordinates measured along the sphere and normal to it.

The question then asks us to explain the numerical results of shear stress $\left( \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2} \right)_{y=0}$ and surface heat transfer rate $\left( -\frac{\partial g}{\partial y} \right)_{y=0}$ when $x=0$ with various value of Pr, which are then given below:
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
 Pr & \left( \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2} \right)_{y=0}  & \left( -\frac{\partial g}{\partial y} \right)_{y=0} \\ \hline
 0.7& 2.4104&0.8150\\ 
1.0 & 2.4104& 0.9336\\
 6.8& 2.4104& 1.8747\\ \hline 
\end{array}$$

1. I couldn't really think of the reason for the constant shear stress in various Pr values. I thought is because we are assuming same dynamical viscosity $\mu$ for all of the Pr values; but then realized the term $\frac{\partial \bar{u}}{\partial \bar{y}}$ in the shear stress formula 
   $\tau = \mu \left( \frac{\partial \bar{u}}{\partial \bar{y}} \right) $is not necessarily constant, so my approach must be wrong.
2. The increase of the surface heat transfer rate is even more puzzling for me. I thought the Prandtl number tells us the qualitative ratio of effects of dissipation to conduction, so a smaller Pr number actually saying heat conduction is more significant compared to convection. So intuitively I will assume $\left( -\frac{\partial g}{\partial y} \right)$  will actually decreases with the increase of Pr values, but the table stated otherwise...

Comment: The first question is easy.  You are assuming temperature-independent viscosity, so the fluid flow receives no feedback (i.e., is decoupled) from the heat transfer.  The second question, you need to work out, perhaps using laminar viscous flow heat transfer in a tube as a simpler example.  Certainly there, for constant Re, the heat transfer coefficient increases with increasing Pr.

Comment: @ChesterMiller Hi, can you please guide me through the reasoning?  For the first part, which we assuming temperature-independent viscosity, do we also have the same velocity profile for all of the Pr values, and we have the same momentum diffusivity for different Pr?

Comment: For the second part, using the definition of heat transfer coefficient $h$ and thermal conductivity:
$$\dot{q} = h(T_{wall} - T_{mean}) \\ \dot{q} = k\left( -\frac{\partial T}{\partial y} \right)_{y=0}$$
we will have the relation 
$$\frac{h}{k}= \frac{\left( -\frac{\partial T}{\partial y} \right)_{y=0}}{T_{wall} - T_{mean}}=\mathrm{constant}$$
So if using the equation of $Pr = c_p \mu /k$, then when Pr increases, k decreases. But when k decreases, $\left( -\frac{\partial T}{\partial y} \right)_{y=0}$ increases. Is this what it supposed to be?

Comment: I haven't taken the time to work out the second part.  Your assessment of the first part is correct.

Comment: The dimensionless temperature gradient is proportional to the radius R divided by the boundary layer thickness.  The boundary layer thickness is on the order of the square root of the thermal diffusivity times contact time.  The thermal diffusivity is proportional to k.  So the temperature gradient is inversely proportional to the square root of k, or directly proportional to the square root of the Prandtl number.

Comment: From the data in your table, it look likes, in this system, the boundary layer thickness is proportional to the thermal diffusivity to (about) the 0.375 power.

Comment: @ChesterMiller Really thank you for your time in explaining all these to me!